# optim function in r returning a list with an error message

Tags: r, r-optimization

I ran the optim function on a function that has 3 numeric parameters.

It did return what looks to be the correct values. 
However, in the message element of the returned list, I got this message:

```
$par
[1] 0.8974235 9.1095283 0.9110162

$value
[1] -614452.9

$counts
function gradient 
      60       60 

$convergence
[1] 52

$message
[1] "ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH"
```

What does that mean?
How can it be remedied?

Comment: When you get a non-zero convergence code then something has gone wrong. We need to see the code and a MWE in order to pinpoint the problem more.

Comment: What does MWE mean? What part of the code do you need to review? The objective function?

Comment: A minimal working example. A complete chunk of code with input and output that produces the error. We cannot see what function you are minimising, how you are calling `optim()`, or what the input parameters are.

Comment: @ekstroem does "LNSRCH" mean linear search? Perhaps my objective function is not linear? It is definitely not analytical. The result returned is based on a data set.